# How to access value of data inside nested object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, react-hooks, jsx

I am new to react and having problem trying to access data inside of the nested object. I am trying to create a app where the condition checks todays date with the date of the list and if the condition is true it returns the list.

The list looks like this :

```
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    name : 'Ashley',
    birthday : {
      year : 1998,
      month: 5,
      date : 22,
    },
    img : 'img'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name : 'Bill',
    birthday : {
      year : 1993,
      month: 2,
      date : 12,
    },
    img : 'img'
  },
];
```

I have made a date object with which the comparision will be done.

```
const today = new Date();
const year = today.getFullYear();
const month = today.getMonth()+1;
const date = today.getDate();
```

In the list, the birthday contains three other values and i can not access them using 'filter' method.

The rest of code are below :

```
function App() {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState(data)
  return (
    <section className = 'container'>
      <h1>{List.length} birthdays today</h1>
    <List people= {people}/>
      <button className="btn" onClick ={() => { setPeople([])}}>Clear All</button>
    </section>
  )
}
```

```
const List = ({people}) =>{
  return (
    <>
     { data.filter((person) => {
       const {id, name, birthday, img} = person;
       const age = year-person.birthday.year;
      if(person.birthday.month === month && person.birthday.date === date){
        return(
         <article className= 'person' key = {id}>
            <h2>{name}</h2>
            <p>{age} years old</p>
            <img src = {img} alt = "person"></img>
         </article>
       )}
       return (
         []
       )
     })} 
    </>
  )
}
```

Sorry about the long description.

Answer (score 2):

The [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function takes a predicate as a parameter that returns true or false, then returns the elements for which the condition is true.

You are returning JSX/an empty array in the predicate, so I am assuming what you want is to actually [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the elements to JSX.

Your code would be:

```
const List = ({people}) =>{
  return (
    <>
      {people.map((person) => {
        const {id, name, birthday, img} = person;
        const age = year - birthday.year;
        if(birthday.month === month && birthday.date === date){
          return (
            <article className='person' key={id}>
                <h2>{name}</h2>
                <p>{age} years old</p>
                <img src={img} alt="person"></img>
            </article>
          )
        }
        return null;
      })} 
    </>
  )
}
```

I have replaced `data` by `people` as it is the correct prop, and `[]` by `null` as `[]` is not valid JSX.

Alternatively, you can `filter` then `map` as follow:

```
const List = ({people}) =>{
  return (
    <>
      {people
        .filter((person) => person.birthday.month === month && person.birthday.date === date)
        .map((person) => {
          const {id, name, birthday, img} = person;
          const age = year - birthday.year;
          return (
            <article className='person' key={id}>
                <h2>{name}</h2>
                <p>{age} years old</p>
                <img src={img} alt="person"></img>
            </article>
          )
        })}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Yep, I think this is a good answer. I didn't catch the `filter` vs `map` issue in mine.

Comment: Thank you, it still shows 'birthday' is assigned a value but never used

Comment: @GauravTamang That's because you are not using the `birthday` value from the destructuring. I updated my answer to fix that.

Comment: I thought filter is used to filter the list and returns only objects that pass the condition.

Comment: `filter` is for filtering indeed, but if you look at the documentation I linked, it only takes the condition for filtering (`birthday.month === month && birthday.date === date` in your case), if you do that, you will still need to chain with `map` in order to transform the elements into JSX to be displayed in your component.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks I didn't know that. I just thought fillter would work similar to map and also display the result. So i need to use map to display the component?

Comment: Yes, the result of the `filter` would be an array of "person" and you still need to map that to valid JSX to be displayed. I have added an example for doing it that way to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be filtering based on the `people` being passed into `List`, not the `data` object.

```js
const List = ({people}) =>{
  return (
    <>
      // instead of data
      { people.filter((person) => {
        const {id, name, birthday, img} = person;
        ...
```

That will allow you to access `id`, `name`, `birthday`, and `img`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing props in curly brackets:

```
<List people= {people}/>
```

it should be passed like this:

```
<List people=people/>
```

and `data.filter` should be replaced with `people.map`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need filter on single object which is inside array

```
const data = [{
id: 1,
name : 'Ashley',
birthday : {
  year : 1998,
  month: 5,
  date : 22,
},
img : 'img'
}]

let birthdayYear = data[0].birthday.year
let birthdayMonth = data[0].birthday.month
let birthdayDay = data[0].birthday.date
```

You can access like this if you have single object only but if multiple then do this

```
const data = [
{
    id: 1,
    name : 'Ashley',
    birthday : {
      year : 1998,
      month: 5,
      date : 22,
    },
    img : 'img'
    },
{
    id: 2,
    name : 'John',
    birthday : {
      year : 1993,
      month: 4,
      date : 12,
    },
    img : 'img'
    }
]

let myObject = data.find(element=> element.id === 2)
let birthdayYear = myObject.birthday.year
let birthdayMonth = myObject.birthday.month
let birthdayDay = myObject.birthday.date
```

let me know if you found this complex

Comment: when you are writing element.id === 2 , does it mean number of items in list is 2?

Comment: Yes you can use map or foreach to iterate the array and and go through all